# how to assign java script value to php variable

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i want to check username in database whether it is there or not while typing

i wrote php coding in same page..i have taken the username by javascript like var `x=document.getElementById("username").value;`

now how to pass value to php code.please give suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery $.getJson and send Json Object to PHP script and use it there. The PHP can return Json value back to the Javascript so it can know how to handle it.

```
$.getJson('php_script.php', '{username:username}', function (returnJson) {
//here you do what you want with the returnJson object
}
```

Comment: `'{username:username}'` is neither JSON nor an object. I suggest to pass an object (`{username:username}`), so that PHP can access the value via `$_GET['username']`.